# create Unique id in a private method createaccountID() without using the uuid

Tags: java, unique-id

The private `createAccountID()` method should create a new unique id everytime an Account is created i.e. the first account created will have the ID
“A1000”. The account ID will increase by 1 for each new account, i.e. the second
will have ID “A1001” etc. and there shouldnt be any duplicates.

I am not really sure how to start this method, except that i created a static variable called counter that is set to 0. I think i have to use a `.equals()` method or something to make sure that the first isn't equal to the new one else it will print an error messege like ("Duplicate")

I am also not sure whether to go with `public void createAccountID()` or
                                      `public String createAccountID()`

Here is the code:

```java
public class Account
{
    private Customer customer;
    private String accountID;
    private double balance;
    private static int counter = 0;
    private static final double OPENING_BALANCE = 0.0;


    public Account()
    {
        setCustomer(new Customer());
        setBalance(OPENING_BALANCE);
        createAccountID();
    }

    public Account(Customer theCustomer, double theBalance)
    {
        setCustomer(theCustomer);
        setBalance(theBalance);
        createAccountID();
    }  

    private void createAccountID()<------------------------------------------------
    {
        accountID = "A";
        for(counter = 0; counter >= 0; ++counter){
            accountID+=counter;//stuck in loop doesnt work.
                                //just thought id try it
        }
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer theCustomer)
    {
        if(theCustomer == null){
            customer = new Customer();
        }
        else{
            customer = theCustomer;
        }
    }

    public Customer getCustomer()
    {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setBalance(double theBalance)
    {
        if(theBalance <= OPENING_BALANCE){
            System.out.println("Error. No Negative values");
        }
        else{
            balance = theBalance;
        }

    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated Cheers

Comment: Is this unique during execution or are they saved, so next time you run it starts off at the next ID

Comment: I believe its supposed to be unique from execution but from the wording its hard to decipher really what it means. because it does said "A1000" is just an example

Answer (score 1):

You can set your 'counter' starting value to 1000 and concatenate it to 'A' char to set in 'accountID'.

To make sure, that there is no duplicates, you can use a Set interface. For example, a HashSet implementation in a private static field.

Another variant is to use a TreeSet and use its last() method to obtain the latest ID. Then you can avoid using a counter. For instance, you can store a starting counter with value '1000' and increment it with treeSet.last() and then store the result.

Also, I`m not sure why do you need a public createAccountID(). This is something, that should be incapsulated inside your class and should not be invoked externally.

Maybe it makes sense to change your accountID field to int and concatenate to 'A' in a getter method.

//
Or maybe you just need a static counter with a starting value '1000' and then call in constructor:

```
this.accountID = 'A' + counter++;
```

Comment: I should have been more specific with my wording. this was for homework so i think i have to call it from inside the constructor, also i have not learned about treeSet or Hashsets yet. so im not sure if i can use them. I will look those up tho to learn from.

Comment: If this is for a homework, set it from the constructor with an AtomicInteger or "this.accountID = 'A' + counter++;" and skip to more interesting things :)

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't multiple threads involved, using the static counter will ensure that there aren't duplicates.

In case of multiple threads, you could use an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). In this case, make sure that first you increment the AtomicInteger with [incrementAndGet(1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet%28%29) and after you create the ID:

```
private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1000);
private static final String PREFIX = "A";

private String accountID;

private void createID() {
    final int number = counter.incrementAndGet(1);
    accountID = PREFIX + number;
}
```

Note that the createID method should be private, as stated by @Michael Cheremukhin.

Comment: I should have been more specific this was for homework, i havent learned how to use the AtomicInteger yet. so i need a way to work with out it because i dont think im allowed to use it.Also  i tried use the 'AtomicInteger'. but is this an abstraction of another class? or is it from a java import? not sure how to access it.

Comment: @user2368486: If you don't use concurrency (AKA Threads), you can use a static int. It guarantees that all objects will have the same value for it. The case of AtomicInteger is only for using when multiple threads are accessing the objects. Don't think about it right now if you don't need it, would be an unneeded complexity. And yes, it is a java import, from the java.util.concurrent.atomic package.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static variable counter, concatenate it to A and increment it. Keep your function private, you shouldn't call it from outside your class.

```
private void createAccountID()
 {
        accountID = "A" + counter++;

 }
```